# How to remove all control and unnecessary chars from string?

Tags: php, html, compression, output

I use output buffer to render some template files and return them as string. Then I use json_encode() to encode these string. Everything is working well but I want to remove all control and unnecessary chars from returned html string to compress the size.

```
{

    "pagination": "<div>\r\n <span>1</span>\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n <a href=\"?p=2\">2</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=3\">3</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=4\">4</a>\r\n <span>...</span>\r\n \r\n <a href=\"?p=64\">64</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=2\">Next</a>\r\n </div>\r\n"

}
```

Thank for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags`

```
$str = "<div>\r\n <span>1</span>\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n <a href=\"?p=2\">2</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=3\">3</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=4\">4</a>\r\n <span>...</span>\r\n \r\n <a href=\"?p=64\">64</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=2\">Next</a>\r\n </div>\r\n";
$str = strip_tags($str);

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$yourtstring="<div>\r\n <span>1</span>\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n <a href=\"?p=2\">2</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=3\">3</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=4\">4</a>\r\n <span>...</span>\r\n \r\n <a href=\"?p=64\">64</a>\r\n <a href=\"?p=2\">Next</a>\r\n </div>\r\n";

$answer = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1',$yourtstring);
```